# Looping Node attribute value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help in processing node attribute value in a loop. Suppose I have a input XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applicationConfiguration>
    <function name="Setting">
        <option name="interface" value="">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-1.address" value="AV:BC:B4:17:63:E0">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-2.address" value="AV:BC:B4:17:53:20">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-3.address" value="11:SD:B4:16:2F:D8">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-4.address" value="34:SD:B4:16:2F:D8">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="sshTunnel" value="">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
    </function>
</applicationConfiguration>
```

Required output XML -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applicationConfiguration>
    <function name="Setting">
        <option name="interface" value="abc">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-1.address" value="test">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-2.address" value="result">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-3.address" value="cdf">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="0-0-4.address" value="34:SD:B4:16:2F:D8">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
        <option name="sshTunnel" value="tunn">
            <configuration>FE</configuration>
        </option>
    </function>
</applicationConfiguration>
```

Want to achieve this functionality using a single template.I have tried below xsl, but won't able to achieve the functionality

XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />    
        <xsl:param name="count" select="0" />
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="'1'" />
        <xsl:variable name="address1" select="'test'" />
        <xsl:variable name="address2" select="'result'" />
        <xsl:variable name="address3" select="'cdf'" />
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="inct">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="3" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="inct" match="option[@name=concat('0-0-',$i,'.address')]/@value"> 
        <xsl:param name="count"/>
        <xsl:param name="i" select="$count" />
        <xsl:param name="limit" select="$count+1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
        <option value="${concat('address',$i,)}">
        </property> 
        <xsl:if test="$count > 1">      
          <xsl:call-template name="inct">               
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="$limit" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly "*output with changed random values*" means? What is the **logic** used in deriving your output from the input? Your non-working code is not helpful in understanding that (or at least I am not smart enough to find that logic there).

Comment: As i showed in my output XML , on the basis of "property/@type" I need to change the @value attribute and those values are not specific .       Logic I used is I have created a template which is implementing this logic to change the value attribute on the basis of this match  ** property[@type=concat('0-0-',$i,'.address')]/@value**  and then calling this template from a loop

Comment: I am afraid that still means nothing to me. Given the input value of "0-0-3.address", how would I arrive at the result of "cd", **using nothing but paper and pencil**?

Comment: I see you now have three variables in your XSLT; `address1`, `address2` and `address3`, and it looks like you are trying to use these variables to update the `value` attribute of the first three "address" `option` elements. However, you output also shows `option` elements with values of "abc" and "tunn" which are not in the input XML or in the XSLT. Could you explain where these come from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***In response to your edited question:***

If, as it seems, you just want to copy the values from the `type` attribute to the `value` attribute, you can do this *very* simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@type"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

> If I change the required Output XML to : `<?xml version="1.0"
>   encoding="UTF-8"?> <root> <property type="0-0-1.address"
>   value="address1">value1</property> <property type="0-0-2.address"
>   value="address2">value4</property> <property type="0-0-3.address"
>   value="address3">value2</property> </root>`

This could be done just as easily by replacing the second template above with:

```
<xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('address', position())"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you transformed it so easily but I think again am not able to explain my actual problem which I want to acheive... Suppose if there is one more  node like  `<property type="test"
  value="abc">testing</property>`  in between above property tags then how can we change  the values for @type="0-0-1/2/3.address"  using one template for address type and another for test type

Comment: @Ruhi it would be best to edit your question and add a small, but complete example of the above input, along with the expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question(input XML along with expected output) with my actual problem

Comment: And now you've gone back to where the logic of the transformation is not clear.

Comment: I have put the logic just to transform option attribute whose @names are like "0-0-1/2/3.address" accordingly I need to change the  @value field . say for i=1 `option[@value=concat('0-0-',i,'.address')] ` it will populate option/@value with address `${concat('address',$i,)}`

Comment: No, that's not what your output shows. And I am afraid I have no more time to spend on this.